# Which permissions are needed to edit Google Storage object metadata?

Tags: perl, google-cloud-storage

I have the following Perl code:

```
  $response = $process->request('PATCH',
                                "https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/$Bucket/o/$EscapedName",
                                '{"content-type": "image/jpeg"}',
#                                 '{"metadata": {"Content-Type": "image/jpeg"}}',
                                {'Content-Type' => 'application/json'});
  unless ($response->is_success) {
    print "Content-Type: text/plain\n\n";
    print $response->status_line . "\n" . $response->decoded_content . "\n" ;
    exit;
  }
```

It produces

```
403 Forbidden
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "insufficientPermissions",
    "message": "Insufficient Permission"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Insufficient Permission"
 }
}
```

despite I have:

- Storage Admin
- Storage Object Admin
- Storage Object Creator
- Storage Object Viewer

enabled for my user.

Why does it not work?

Simple uploading of objects does work, but I cannot set this metadata.

Comment: According to https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/patch , you need to have `OWNER` on the object, but I don't see any documentation how Admin includes (or doesn't include) `OWNER` ...

Comment: are you able to run in the [API explorer](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/buckets/patch) It also lists the following scope requirements: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform and  https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.full_control

Comment: Alternatively can you try the [gsutil](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/viewing-editing-metadata#edit) tool to edit the metadata?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To update the object metadata ones needs the `storage.objects.update` permission.  From [Cloud Storage IAM Permissions](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-permissions):

> Object permissions
>
> ...
>
> ```
> storage.objects.update    Update object metadata, excluding ACLs.
> ```

But both `roles/storage.objectAdmin` and `roles/storage.admin` roles (assuming that's what you mean by the roles you listed) *should* already include that permission, so something else may be at work. From [Standard roles](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-roles#standard-roles):

```
roles/storage.objectAdmin  Full control over objects, including listing,    storage.objects.*
                           creating, viewing, and deleting objects.
                           Does not grant permission to read or edit 
                           bucket metadata.
roles/storage.admin        Full control of buckets and objects.             storage.buckets.*
                           When applied to an individual bucket, control    storage.objects.*
                           only to the specified bucket and objects within
                           the bucket.
```

Answer (score 3):

The name of the attribute in the Object resource is `contentType`, you are passing `content-type`:

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects